# How to add React to an Express app?

Tags: express, reactjs

I'm developing an app using Express and I'd like to run React on the front-end. How should I go about this?

I've seen people adding script tags (using CNDs) to their layout files, others using many npm packages...

What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

ES6 (with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) is used, buy you don't have to.

**server.js**

```
import "babel-core/polyfill";
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import React, { DOM } from "react";
import ServerDOM from "react-dom/server";
import Html from "./components/Html";

const server = express();

server.set("port", (process.env.PORT || config.port));
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
server.use("/", (req, res, next) =>
{
    const html = ServerDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(Html));
    res.status(200).send("<!doctype html>" + html);
});

server.get("*", async (req, res, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        let statusCode = 200;
        const html = ServerDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(Html));

        res.status(statusCode).send("<!doctype html>" + html);
    }
    catch (e) { next(e) }
});

server.listen(server.get("port"), () =>
{
    console.log("\nServer running at localhost:%d\n", server.get("port"));
});
```

**Html.js** *(component)*

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes, DOM, createElement as $ } from "react";

class Html extends Component
{
    static propTypes =
    {
        title: PropTypes.string,
        description: PropTypes.string
    };

    static defaultProps =
    {
        title: "",
        description: ""
    };

    render()
    {
        const { title, description, children } = this.props;

        return (
            DOM.html({},
                DOM.head({},
                    DOM.meta({charSet: "utf-8"}),
                    DOM.meta({httpEquiv: "X-UA-Compatible", content: "IE=edge"}),
                    DOM.meta({name: "description", content: description}),
                    DOM.meta({name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}),
                    DOM.link({rel: "stylesheet", href: "/app.css", type: "text/css"}),
                    DOM.title({}, title)
                ),
                DOM.body({},
                    DOM.div({id: "app"}, children),
                    DOM.script({src: "/app.js"})
                )
            )
        )
    }
}

export default Html;
```

In theory, you are setting up simple express server and using ServerDOM which is react js server side rendering to render the Html component.
Then you including file like `app.js` which could be a bundle compiled using something like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) (only if you want, I'll extremely recommend it) then you simply put it on the Html component and you done.